# Unable to got internet access in virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

What should be the networking settings in virtual box such that virtual machines can talk to each other and can access internet as well?

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox click on File/Preferences/Network and create a new NAT network. Then go to the network settings of your virtual machine, select "nat network" and choose the nat network name you just created.
All virtual machines connected to the same nat network should be able to talk to each other.

Alternatively you can also select bridged adapter in all VMs. But that is less secure. If e.g. some malware infects one of your virtual machines it could access your whole home network including your host OS, your TV, router, etc.

Comment: thanks #spiderpig for answer, but now both VMs have same ip address,but they should have different ip address and as well as internet connectivity now what to do next?

Comment: Make sure both VMs have a different MAC address. Go to network/advanced and click on the symol right next to "Mac Address" to generate a new random address. If that doesn't cause the VMs to automatically also aquire different IP addresses, you need to set them manually in the network settings of the guest OS.

Comment: Both have different MAC address, but still they have same ip address. Moreover, in manual settings I set adapter 1 to NAT and adapter 2 to Host-only network, now both VMs (Win xp & Kali linux) have their unique ip address but now the main problem is that win xp is able to got internet access while kali linux is not.  why?